# GDAL calculation stop working python.exe any time

Tags: python, gdal, python-2.7, osgeo4w

i try to use python GDAL raster calculation to take some raster result where i need.

i windows user and i work in OSGeo4W Shell.

first i try to work using batch file with success.

code work with batch file :

```
import os
os.system("C:/xxx/xxx/path/test.bat ")
```

batch file :

```
gdal_calc.py -A C:/xxx/xxx/path/a_layer.tif -B C:/xxx/xxx/path/a_layer.tif --outfile=C:/xxx/xxx/path/a_layer.tif --calc="(2*A)+(2*B)"
```

all work without error.

but if i try to wotk using python then any time before complete my script then `python.exe` crashed.any time

try using python script :

```
call('python C:/OSGeo4W64/bin/gdal_calc.py -A {0} -B {1} -C {2} --outfile={3} --calc="(2*A)+(2*B)"'.format(a_layer,b_layer,out_layer))
```

i want to use python script because i have many options for working usnig python and gdal.

but can someone to tell me why batch file work and not python script ?

**edit**

if `print 'PATHEXT'` environment variable in OSGeo4W Shell i dont have `'.PY'` extesion.but if is this hte problem can i define `'PATHEXT'` inside some python script ?

Comment: Do you get an error message, if so what is it? IMO writing the batch file and executing is better, but I use subprocess.Popen to run the scripts as call can be flaky, something to do with paths not being set right I think. You could try to execute with subprocess.Popen but your string needs to be a list.

Comment: @Michael Stimson just take error message `stop working python.exe `.can you show me some example using subprocess.Popen ?

Comment: You should do these calculations directly with `osgeo.gdal` and NumPy; see [the example for `CreateCopy()`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html) to get an idea how to do this in a more Python way

Answer (score 1):

This is part of a **much** bigger process

```
import os, sys, subprocess

InFolder = sys.argv[1]
OutFDS   = sys.argv[2]
DatumAdj = sys.argv[3]

DatAdjust     = r'd:\path\to\AdjustToDatum.py'
PythonEXE     = r'C:\path\to\python.exe'

TempName = 'xx' + fNam + '.shp'
TempFC   = os.path.join(InFolder,TempName)
thisID   = 1

proc = subprocess.Popen([PythonEXE, DatAdjust,TempFC,DatumAdj,str(thisID)])
proc.communicate() # wait until process ends
```

This shows calling a python script with [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) successfully. I have *very much* simplified this process; in my script I create a list of process objects and `poll` them in a loop adding a new process as the finish so that a maximum number of processes execute at the same time.